Pylance complaining for sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
I am using Pylance with Type Checking Mode: Basic and I am loading the iris dataset with sklearn.datasets.load_iris().
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

def main():
    iris = load_iris()
    data = iris.data

This code works for the Python interpreter but Pylance complains giving:

Cannot access member "data" for type "tuple[Bunch, tuple[Unknown, ...]]"
Member "data" is unknown Pylance(reportAttributeAccessIssue)

So I tried type hinting hope to solve the issue adding
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
    iris: Bunch = load_iris()

And now I get:

Expression of type "tuple[Bunch, tuple[Unknown, ...]]" cannot be assigned to declared type "Bunch"
"tuple[Bunch, tuple[Unknown, ...]]" is incompatible with "Bunch" Pylance(reportAssignmentType)

If instead I follow the suggestion of Pylance and unpack it as it was a tuple (which is not according to the docs) and do:
iris: Bunch
iris, _ = load_iris()

Pylance warnings disappear but the code no longer works with error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../main.py", line 10, in 
main()
File ".../main.py", line 6, in main
iris, _ = load_iris()
^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Looking at the source and the docs load_iris() should return a Bunch object not a tuple of two nor a tuple with more than two elements.
I would like to fix this with something other than # type: ignore and to fully understand the issue.


Looking at the source and the docs load_iris() should return a Bunch object not a tuple of two nor a tuple with more than two elements.

Pylance is using a very inaccurate stub for sklearn, and sklearn.datasets.load_iris is declared as such:
def load_iris(
    *, return_X_y: bool = False, as_frame: bool = False
) -> tuple[Bunch, tuple]:
    ...

I'm not sure if it had been right for a historical version of sklearn, but at least it's obviously wrong for the current version.

I would like to fix this with something other than # type: ignore

I'd say don't bother. It's probably doable by fixing the stub, but I don't think it'll be worth the work.

So basically it's a mistake in sklearn, Pyright is working just fine, did I understand correctly? Since the implementation of the function is done in Python how come stubs are needed? From what I have read they are needed when modules are written in other languages

Technically speaking, it's a mistake in Pylance instead of SKLearn. But even if Pylance didn't use an inaccurate stub, you would still face a similar issue, because Pyright would then infer an inaccurate signature of load_iris directly from its implementation.

Stubs are not required, as long as the code is either simple or correctly annotated with types. But sadly that's not true with SKLearn. Code in SKLearn is AFAICT fully untyped. And even for a seemingly simple function like load_iris, it's written with a combination of an untyped decorator, multi-dispatching and calling other untyped functions.
